# CSS transition stuttering, but only on my 60hz monitor

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, multiple-monitors

I seem to have an issue in Chrome 83 with a duo-monitor setup (144hz primary, 60hz secondary), not sure if it's a bug with Chrome, a bug with my code, or intended behavior. I'll explain my test case first.

I've got two divs. One has a hidden iframe, we'll get to why later.

```
<div id="content1"></div>
<div id="content2">
  <iframe id="video" hidden ...></iframe>
</div>
```

Both divs are the size of the viewport, with the latter one being fixed to peek out from the bottom of the viewport, appearing as a footer. The animation I want is for the footer to slide up and cover the entire viewport, and then slide back down again. I'm doing this by animating `transform: translateY();` which should be performant. Here is the CSS.

```
#content1 {
  height: 100vh;
}

#content2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(100vh - 50px);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 350ms ease-in;
}

#content2[show] {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100vh + 50px));
}
```

This is buttery smooth on my 144hz monitor, staying steady at around 144(+-10) FPS. However, dragging Chrome over to my 60hz monitor I suddenly get terrible stuttering and uneven framerate, anywhere from 200 FPS to 30 FPS.

And here is another strange thing. If I play a video in the footer div, such as by embedding a YouTube video with an iframe, suddenly the performance stays solid at 144(+-10) FPS, still on my 60hz monitor.

I've also tried with Chrome halfway between the two monitors, and this behaves the same as only having it on the 60hz. It only seems to behave properly when it's solely on the 144hz.

This issue affects all CSS transitions, I've tried it with the transform, opacity and top properties. It does however not affect scrolling performance.

Here is a codepen with the example: https://codepen.io/Ophion/full/BajJEjm Click the footer to trigger the animation, and hit space to reveal the YouTube video inside of the footer.

I'm really curious if anyone else can reproduce this issue or knows why it happens.

Comment: Have you tried adding `rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)` to all your transforms to make them gpu accelerated? This usually resolves rendering glitches with transforms.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this as well as other common tricks like translateZ, will-change, etc. It doesn't seem to make any difference.